# How to extract a table from website without specifying the web browser in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, request, screen-scraping

I'm trying to automate data extraction from ASX (https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz) website into my database by writing a web scraping python script and deploying it in Azure Databrick. Currently, the script I have is working in Visual Studio Code, but when I try to run it in databrick, it crashes, throwing the error below.

```
Could not get version for google-chrome with the command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version || google-chrome-beta --version || google-chrome-dev --version
```

I believe I will need to simplify my code in order to obtain the table without mentioning the we browser.

My sample code is below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
#browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver',options=options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
browser.get('https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz')
time.sleep(3)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
market_dataset = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'market-dataset'})
market_dataset
```

I tried to use the below code instead, with just the `request` package, but it failed since it couldn't find the 'market-dataset' `div class`.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


URL = "https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
market_dataset = soup.findAll("div",href=True,attrs={'class':'market-dataset'})
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: You either scrape the raw HTML without a browser, but then that HTML must contain your desired data. If that’s dynamically loaded via Javascript, then you either need to dig deeper and figure out where it gets its data from, or you do need to use a headless browser, which you would then also need to install on Azure.

Comment: it uses JavaScript to load data from https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz/dataset

Comment: your `findAll("div",href=True, ...` tries to find `<div href="...">` but this page doesn't have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to load table from https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz/dataset

Server checks if it is AJAX/XHR request so it needs header

```
 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

But your `findAll("div",href=True, ...` tries to find `<div href="...">` but this page doesn't have it - so I search normal `<div>` with `class="market-dataset"`

---

Minimal working code.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0', 
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'     
}

URL = "https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_nz/dataset"
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
market_dataset = soup.findAll("div", attrs={'class':'market-dataset'})
print('len(market_dataset):', len(market_dataset))
```

Result:

```
len(market_dataset): 10
```